# What is a good results/reach rate for Facebook ads aimed at reactions on events?

Tags: facebook

I'm a beginner using Facebook ad management and launching ads for a small non-profit organization. I have been reviewing the results of my ads but I have no references to know if my ads are doing well or not. The ads aimed towards reactions on events have yielded less results than those aimed at involvement or reach. Personally, I think this makes sense because the threshold to click on "I'm going" is higher than to watch a video for example. Still, I would like to know what kind of results I should be expecting for ads aimed towards reactions on events in order to know if my ads are doing well or not. Can someone give me any indications for this? I've tried googling this, but I haven't found anything helpful. It could be that I'm not using the right terminology or looking in the right places, since I'm still very much a beginner.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not an actual programming question.

Comment: Any suggestion for a better location? I don't really know where else to post this.